# Centering element in grid layout Tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm struggeling to center a element in a grid layout. I want the blue bordered item in the center of the red item.

[image: Tailwind example]

I added the code in play.tailwind: https://play.tailwindcss.com/cmaOoeaZqe

I've tried different things with flex place-items-center, justify-center, justify-self-center, etc but it doesn't work.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `flex flex-col` to the parent div. Than, replace the `mb-4 ml-1` from the label with `mx-auto`. The `mx-auto` will set both left and right margins to auto, which basically aligns the label centered.

See: https://play.tailwindcss.com/5z7IcmnM9l

Comment: Thanks! Apparently it was simple..